# Redirect low performance pc

Tags: javascript

I am building a website which has lots of animation and for my notebook, the animations are lagging because my notebook isn t that good. How can I find out if the user's pc is good enough to load all the animations ok or I need to redirect him to another website? I want to do a script that gives a grade for that pc but i do not know how to get graphic card ,cpu and ram info.

Comment: I don't think that kind of information can be obtained through javascript. Maybe consider coding a "lite" version of your website that people can opt to use if they see that the main version is laggy for them?

Comment: ^^^ also consider if those animation are actually necessary for your site.  And as a side note, you might be interested in: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: maybe you shouldn't make a website with a lot of animations at first place, did you think about mobile users? do you really think your animations are going to play well on phones? no, stop doing this. If you trully need to make some 'interactive experience' then make it optional for the user who visits your website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot really get the specs of the clients hardware, but you can actually measure the FPS:

```
const start = Date.now();
let frames = 0;
(function tick() {
   frames++;
   requestAnimationFrame(tick);
})();
```

So after a few seconds you could check if the FPS rate is under a certain level:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  const fps = frames * 1000 / (Date.now() - start) ;
  if(fps < 50) {
    // Redirect ...
  }
}, 3000);
```